# I do not understand behavior of current in 74HC4066

Tags: current, datasheet

From the [Nexperia 74HC4066 datasheet](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT4066.pdf), page 4, table 4, footnote 1, what does it mean:

> To avoid drawing VCC current out of terminal Z, when switch current flows in terminals Yn, the voltage drop across the bidirectional
> switch must not exceed 0.4 V

[image: table 4 and footnotes from Nexperia 74HC4066 datasheet]

It is not clear to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What it means is that there is an asymmetry between Z and Y and if the voltage drop across the switch (**when the switch is 'on', only**) is too large then some current will come from Vcc, which may be unwanted.

As to why it happens, it's not immediately clear to me. 0.4V sounds like a diode drop. Maybe some kind of parasitic transistor or isolation diode.  The same warning appears in Nexperia's datasheet for the 74HC4016 and their HEF4016B.

A similar warning appears in TI's [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd74hc4066.pdf).

> 1. In certain applications, the external load-resistor current may include both Vcc and signal-line components. To avoid drawing Vcc
>    current when switch current flows into the transmission gate inputs,
>    (terminals 1, 4, 8 and 11) the voltage drop across the bidirectional
>    switch must not exceed 0.6V (calculated from RON values shown in the
>    DC Electrical Specifications Table). No Vcc current will flow through
>    \$\text R_L\$ if the switch current flows into terminals 2, 3, 9 and 10.

And even in the 1994 Motorola datasheet for the MC14016B where they make it clear it's a bipolar junction effect by specifying 600mV at low temperature and 300mV at high temperature.

It does not appear in 1974/1978 RCA and Motorola datasheets for the 4016 however it's quite possible it had not been noticed at that time since we usually try to keep the voltage across the switches at a minimum when 'on'.

---

So keep the voltage across the switch, when on, and in the undesirable direction less than a few hundred mV depending on your accuracy requirements and temperature range. Since the 'on' resistance *increases* with temperature and the mystery diode drop *decreases* with temperature, maximum junction temperature (and minimum supply voltage) is the worst-case. At 4.5V that would imply a maximum current of a couple mA.

A mirrored warning (GND current) does appear on [Nexperia](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74LVC1G66.pdf)'s 74LVC1G66 datasheet.

Comment: Nexperia's 74LVC1G66 page 4, table 4, footnote 1

Comment: Similar anomaly but GND current for the 74LVC1G66.

Comment: Seems like they float the N-well for the PMOSs on the 74LVC1G66 while it’s opposite (P-well on NMOS) on the other chip. The 4016 doesn’t seem to do this and looks to be a textbook transmission gate. I believe these floating body tricks are what might give the 4066 the lower ON resistance versus the 4016??? Anyway, it’s interesting to know the 4066 has this property. Never noticed it before.

Comment: @SteKulov The HEF4016B and MC14016B have the same warning though. This could be a real gotcha in some designs and would be troublesome to diagnose. I could see losing a few days of your life tracking that down if it wasn't spelled out in the datasheet like it is now.

Comment: Oh ok. Good point. I was only looking at 74HC/HCT series.

Answer (score 9):

It means that when the voltage across the switch is less than 0.4 V, all the current at Z comes from Y, which is another way of saying the switch is effectively isolated from the supply pins.

If the voltage across the switch exceeds 0.4 V, then some or all of the current at Z will come from VCC. The switch is no longer isolated from the supply pins. In a measurement setting, if you are expecting the to multiplex a current measuring device at Z between the Y pins, you are no longer measuring the Y current, but something different.

To keep the switch isolated, as you would expect a mechanical switch or set of relay contacts to be, keep the current through the switch low enough that the voltage drop across the switch stays below 0.4 V.

Comment: What is Vsw = -0,5V? when is Vy - Vz = 0,5V -> Vsw = 0,5; or Vz - Vy = 0,5V -> Vsw = -0,5

Comment: @agusha It's expressed as the magnitude of the voltage drop. It then goes on to talk about current direction with respect to the Z input, which means that only one polarity of excess switch voltage is actually to be avoided. Frankly, I can't be bothered to work out which way round the spec should be written to express that, data sheets often get that sort of polarity wrong, and I often understand it wrong, you work it out. I would not stress those switches above 0.4 V in either direction anyway, from dissipation and general caution grounds.

Answer (score 2):

Although the 4066 uses MOSFETs as its primary switching elements, it is constructed in such a way that parts of it behave like an NPN transistor with the collector tied to VDD, the emitter tied to the "output", and the base switched between the "input" and ground.  Because a MOSFETs will short the base and emitter whenever the switch is "on", there normally won't be enough voltage between the base and emitter for the NPN transistor's behavior to affect anything.  If enough current current flows through the switch that its voltage drop would allow the base-emitter junction to start conducting, however, that current will be supplemented with collector current drawn from VDD.

In many applications, this behavior would be desirable.  The 4066 is often used to connect two buses so that when either is driven, the other will be as well.  Devices that drive buses are often have more ability to pull a bus low than to pull it high; if one side of the device is being driven low and the other side has acquiesced to be pulled low, and the driven side of the device is switched high, the 4066 will supplement the current from the driven side (which might be pulled up somewhat weakly) so as to pull up the other side reasonably firmly.  If instead the "output" side is supposed to switch the other side low, the 4066 will fight it slightly, but since low-side drivers are generally stronger than high-side drivers, this wouldn't be a problem.

On the other hand, there are some applications where it's important that all current that flows in one of the switch terminals must precisely match that flowing out the other.  For example, one might have a switched-capacitor filter which is supposed to connect a capacitor to an input voltage, let its voltage settle to match the input, disconnect it from the input, and then connect it to another capacitor so as to produce a weighted average of the previous output voltage and the new input voltage.  Having extra current added to the output from VDD would cause the output capacitor to receive an inaccurate voltage.  Other switches like the 4016 would have a higher "on" resistance, but would not introduce unwanted charge from VDD.

Comment: Ah interesting. Is this parasitic BJT effect due to the way they are floating the body terminals of the MOSFETs in the 4066 while the 4016 looks to be a textbook transmission gate?

Comment: @SteKulov: I wouldn't think the body terminals would be left floating, but that terminals which aren't explicitly marked otherwise would be instead be connected to VSS or VDD.  One of the FETs does get its body explicitly tied to the "input" side of the transmission gate, however.

Comment: Oh sorry. By “floating” I didn’t mean they float fully and indefinitely. There’s an NMOS that can switch that “input” side body terminal thing you’re talking about to GND. It’s similar to a technique they use to make 5V tolerant I/O: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/616014/how-can-you-block-the-parasitic-body-diode-in-digital-cmos-i-o-ic-design

Answer (score 1):

All this really means is that the switch isn't quite bidirectional. To have it act as a switch where currents on both sides of the closed switch are same:

**Z must be no lower than 0.4V below Y when the switch is *closed***.

Or

**Current must flow into the Z terminal, and out of the Y terminal**.

That is, when there's a load on the switch heavy enough to drop more than 0.4V across the switch, the current must be flowing into the Z terminal. If the current flows *out* of the Z terminal, then as soon as Z is 0.4V lower than Y terminal (or more), the Z current will be shared between Y and VCC. This breaks the assumption of "normal" behavior similar to that of a mechanical switch.

A mechanical switch would have no preference which way the current flows.